# JQuery AJAX vs AngularJs $http.post() when using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Which is better, **JQuery AJAX** or **AngularJs $http.post**? And why? Which should I use?

I mean better not just in terms of performance, but any other relevant feature.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS, with his $http service, implements JSON-related securities (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations), so I recommend you to use $http.

If you want to use jQuery $.ajax service, keep in mind you need to apply your scope modifications :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.add.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"num1": num1, "num2": num2},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){   
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.result = response;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically both methods are good. But according to my opinion AJAX method is good. Because only need to include jQuery library. While in AngularJS method you have to include jQuery and AngularJS framework.

Thanks...